# Exception of Unknown kind of function call

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript-vm

I am using remix IDE and I am getting this error:

```
Internal exception in StandardCompiler::compileInternal: /src/libsolidity/ast/ASTJsonConverter.cpp(791): Throw in function string dev::solidity::ASTJsonConverter::functionCallKind(dev::solidity::FunctionCallKind)
    Dynamic exception type: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implIN3dev8solidity21InternalCompilerErrorEEE
    std::exception::what: std::exception
    [PN3dev11tag_commentE] = Unknown kind of function call .
```

How to fix this problem.

Comment: What code are your trying to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compiler bug in Solidity 0.4.12. You can view the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2517).

For now you should just use Solidity version 0.4.11